# Boundedness of the first Fréchet derivative

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, frechet-derivative

Let $(E,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$ be a normed vector space and $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a twice Fréchet differentiable function with $\sup_{x \in E} \frac{\vert f(x)\vert}{1+\Vert x\Vert^3} < \infty$ as well as
\begin{align}
\Vert D^2f(x+h) - D^2f(x) \Vert_L < C_1 \Vert h\Vert \qquad \forall x,h \in E
\end{align}
for some constant $C_1$. For a multilinear form $B$ on $E$ we used here the notation $\Vert B \Vert_L:=\sup_{\Vert x \Vert=1} \vert B[x,\ldots,x]\vert $.

Why does this imply
\begin{align}
\Vert Df(x)\Vert_L < C_2 (1+\Vert x\Vert^2) \qquad \forall x \in E
\end{align}
for some constant $C_2$?

Comment: Apparently the condition on the supremum above is not even needed (see the answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y\in E$ arbitrary. Then
$$
F(t)=Df(tx)(y), \quad t\in\mathbb R,
$$
is a real valued differentiable function and $F'(t)=D^2f(tx)(x,y)$. Mean Value theorem implies that, there exists a $t^*\in (0,1)$, such that
$$
Df(x)(y)-Df(0)(y)=F(1)-F(0)=F'(t^*)=D^2f(t^*x)(x,y)
$$
Hence
$$
\| Df(x)(y) \| =\|D^2f(t^*x)(x,y)+Df(0)(y)\|\le \|D^2f(t^*x)\|\|x\|\|y\|+\|Df(0)\|\|y\|
$$
and thus
$$
\| Df(x)\| \le \|D^2f(t^*x)\|\|x\|+\|Df(0)\| \\
\le \|D^2f(t^*x)-D^2f(0)\|\|x\|+\|D^2f(0)\|\|x\|+\|Df(0)\|
\\ \le C_1 \|t^*x\|\|x\|+\|D^2f(0)\|\|x\|+\|Df(0)\| \\ \le C_1\|x\|^2+\|D^2f(0)\|\|x\|+\|Df(0)\| 
$$